get values from nested object and display in a grid on angular 17
I have this JSON:
{
  "mainObjeto": {
    "id": 1,
    "descripcion": "some text",
    "reclamoMotivo": {
      "id": 3,
      "nombre": "yyyyy",
      "descripcion": "Producto con Defectos"
    },
    "empresa": {
      "id": 1,
      "nombreEmpresa": "xxxx",
      "descripcionEmpresa": "xxxx"
    },
    "adjuntos": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "nombreAdjunto": "test.txt"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "nombreAdjunto": "prueba.jpeg"
      }
    ],
    "fechaCreacion": "2024-10-06T18:22:55.202+00:00",
    "correoCliente": "cleinte@mail.com",
    "reclamoEstado": {
      "id": 1,
      "reclamoEstadoMaestro": {
        "id": 2,
        "nombreEstado": "EN_REVISION",
        "descripcion": "En revisión"
      },
      "commentSupport": "falla sistema",
      "updatedAt": "2024-10-06T18:22:55.315+00:00",
      "correoAsesor": "cleinte@mail.com"
    }
  }
}

I need to populate the values in a grid using angular, for testing purposes I tried to get the data with:
<div class="bank" *ngFor="let item of list">
  <p *ngFor="let itemAux of item | keyvalue">
    Key: <b>{{itemAux.key}},</b> value: <b> {{itemAux.value}} |</b>
  </p>
</div>

this is my ts code:
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.service.getData()
    .subscribe( data => { this.objs = data  });
}

but I get this value:
Key: mainObjeto, value: [object Object]
Please your help

This is expected. {{itemAux.value}} contains the full-blown object. In order to present this to the user, it needs to be converted to string. So Angular calls toString(), which results in the [object Object] string you are seeing. It is not clear what you are expecting.

@JSONDerulo Thanks for your response I need to populate all the json value that is the result from a httpclient call, in a grid but what I get in the component.html is this value [object Object] I need to view the properties of that Json (httclient response) , for example the value of the "descripcion" field, that is "some text" the same with the others fields. My objective is to populate those values in a grid

You can directly access the properties of mainObjeto and its nested objects.
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { YourService } from './your.service'; // Adjust the import according to your service path

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  objs: any; // Define the type according to your data structure

  constructor(private service: YourService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getData().subscribe(data => {
      this.objs = data;
    });
  }
}

In your HTML template, you can access the nested properties directly
    <div *ngIf="objs">
  <h3>Main Object Details</h3>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Descripcion</th>
      <th>Motivo</th>
      <th>Empresa</th>
      <th>Fecha Creación</th>
      <th>Correo Cliente</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ objs.mainObjeto.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ objs.mainObjeto.descripcion }}</td>
      <td>{{ objs.mainObjeto.reclamoMotivo.nombre }}</td>
      <td>{{ objs.mainObjeto.empresa.nombreEmpresa }}</td>
      <td>{{ objs.mainObjeto.fechaCreacion | date:'short' }}</td>
      <td>{{ objs.mainObjeto.correoCliente }}</td>
      <td>{{ objs.mainObjeto.reclamoEstado.reclamoEstadoMaestro.nombreEstado }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <h3>Adjuntos</h3>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let adjunto of objs.mainObjeto.adjuntos">
      {{ adjunto.nombreAdjunto }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


Thanks for your answer, you gave an idea of what was happening with my code, I had to do some logic because I got an array of objects from api response.

Try accessing the value of mainObjeto, since it contains the properties that you want to iterate. I am also using json pipe to view the contents of complex objects.
To use the json pipe in HTML, make sure you import either CommonModule or JsonPipe to the imports array of the standalone component or module.
<div class="bank" *ngFor="let item of list">
  <p *ngFor="let itemAux of item.mainObjeto | keyvalue">
    Key: <b>{{itemAux.key}},</b> value: <b> {{itemAux.value | json}} |</b>
  </p>
</div>


You need to flatten the nested object structure before displaying it. This can be done in your component by extracting the relevant fields.
    objs: any; // To hold the fetched data
      displayData: any[] = []; // To hold flattened data for display

    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getData().subscribe(data => {
      this.objs = data;
      this.flattenData(this.objs.mainObjeto);
    });
  }

flattenData(data: any) {
    this.displayData = [{
      id: data.id,
      descripcion: data.descripcion,
      reclamoMotivoNombre: data.reclamoMotivo.nombre,
      empresaNombre: data.empresa.nombreEmpresa,
      fechaCreacion: new Date(data.fechaCreacion).toLocaleString(),
      correoCliente: data.correoCliente,
      reclamoEstadoNombre: data.reclamoEstado.reclamoEstadoMaestro.nombreEstado,
      commentSupport: data.reclamoEstado.commentSupport
    }];}

Now, create a grid to display the flattened data. You can use a simple table for this:
    <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Descripción</th>
      <th>Motivo</th>
      <th>Empresa</th>
      <th>Fecha de Creación</th>
      <th>Correo Cliente</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
      <th>Comentario Soporte</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of displayData">
      <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.descripcion }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.reclamoMotivoNombre }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.empresaNombre }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.fechaCreacion }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.correoCliente }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.reclamoEstadoNombre }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.commentSupport }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

